# NavigationDrawer ListView does not show up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, navigation-drawer, android-layout-weight

I use the ActionBarDrawerToggle to open and close the DrawerLayout.
But the listView inside my drawerlayout is not shown.

```
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) mDrawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerList.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.abs__background_holo_light));
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, 
            R.string.open, R.string.close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

 // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

It shows only a black drawer without entries.
The drawerList should be white as set in "setBackgroundColor" and the drawerList should display the entries form the adapter.

When I open the drawer with openDrawer(mDrawerList) it works, but not on swipe.

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
    //if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
    //          return true;
    //}

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        break;
```

Here is the main.xml layout with the DrawerLayout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content -->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/activeRemindersList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.colapps.reminder.fragments.ActiveRemindersFragment" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

Can anybody help?

**UPDATE:**

The problem seems is the Fragment.
If I add instead of the Fragment a simple FrameLayout all is working fine:

```
<!-- The main content -->

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test" />
</FrameLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

The problem was that in the Fragment Layout was also a "DrawerLayout".

I have changed a lot and forgotten to remove it from the Fragment Layout.

Thanks to all who have tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure this has either something to do with:

- the ListView not having a **weight** property
- the ListView adapter being **empty**
- the ListView being **hidden by the Fragment**

Try changing the layot file so that the ListView has a weight property as well and change the height property of the Fragment. Furthermore, put both of them in a **LinearLayout**.

Also make sure you have **thesemethods overridden in your Activity**:

```
/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Use the `onDrawerItemSelected(int pos)` method to add / replace Fragments.

```
@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(int pos) {     

     // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (pos) {
    case 0:         
        fragment = new FragOne();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FragTwo();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new FragThree();
        break;
    }
    // R.id.content_frame is the id of the FrameLayout
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit() 

    // update selected item then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(pos, true);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Here you have a **detailed tutorial / example** of how to implement the NavigationDrawer. When I first used the NavigationDrawer I went by this tutorial and was able to successfully implement it.

> http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: On the DrawerLayout there is no need for a weight, because it is overlapped.
And it is working if I call "openDrawer" and don't use the ActionBarDrawerToggle.

And at least it should have the set backgroundcolor.

Comment: Could you have a look at my updated answer and see if it works now?

Comment: I have already this methods in my main activity and it does not work.

Comment: Well then I'm quite out of ideas. I would have to see more of your code. Please have a look here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: I think I found the problem.
It seems my Fragment is the problem. If I remove the fragment and add a FrameLayout with a TextView in it, it works.

If I add the Fragment again I have a black empty drawer.
But I don't understand why.

Comment: Well this is because you should use the onDrawerItemSelected() method and add/replace the fragments in there referencing the FrameLayout. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `<FrameLayout>` in your XML (notice the one I have wrapping the fragment content).

It should look something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/app_info_fragment_phone"
            ... />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        ... />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: No succes! If I add a FrameLayout the Fragment ist not displayed. I get then a white empty page and the Drawer is only black as before.

Comment: You may have more than one problem.  I am pretty sure you need the FrameLayout (I took my working example exactly from the documentation).  Good luck.